# DBT invalid snapshot time error with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have data held in BigQuery, and I run DBT against tables and populate new tables in BigQuery. I call `dbt run` every 5 mins via `cron`. I also run `dbt test` every hour, to check data consistency.

`dbt run` always runs successfully, I have never had any problems. However, sometimes when running `dbt test` I occasionally see (perhaps once every 20 runs), the following error:

`Invalid snapshot time 1595674825279 for table xxx:dbt_stg.stg_journey_detail. Cannot read before 1595674825283`

The failing test is always the one that tests for a non-null primary key on a particular table. The table is an intermediate table that looks like this:

```
with dedupe as (
    select * EXCEPT(row_num) from (
            select * from (
              select *, row_number() over (
                  partition by id
                  order by updated_at desc
              ) as row_num
              from {{ source('master', 'journey_detail') }}
            )
          ) as journey_detail_dedupe
        where journey_detail_dedupe.row_num = 1
)

select
    * except (id, pausable),
    id as journey_detail_id,
    pausable as is_pausable

from dedupe
```

The test looks like this:

```
  - name: stg_journey_detail
    description: This model cleans up the journey detail table
    columns:
      - name: journey_detail_id
        description: Primary key
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
```

It looks like BigQuery never got as far as actually running the query, so I suspect this error was generated by DBT. If I look in the BigQuery logs for the test name, I can see other times when this query was actually  run, and this is the query:

```
/* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "0.17.0", "profile_name": "beryl", "target_name": "default", "node_id": "test.beryl.not_null_stg_journey_detail_journey_detail_id"} */

select count(*) as validation_errors
from `beryl-basis-development`.`dbt_stg`.`stg_journey_detail`
where journey_detail_id is null
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the query that BigQuery ran? You should be able to find in within dbt logs and/or the BQ logs

Comment: Post updated - I've added the query that gets run by this test, but it doesn't look like BQ gets as far as actually running it when I get the error message.